# Simple way to move <script> code to JS file

Tags: javascript, html, navbar

I have a simple question. Using is sample code, I just want to move the JS code from my `.html` file to an external `.js` file.

I have tried moving all the code that is currently within `<script></script>` to `themes.js`, then adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="themes.js"></script>` to my `.html` file, but I get many error alerts while composing `themes.js`. Some help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div id="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
  <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>

<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: can you please tell us the error, also if it's 404 not found then the directory for the .html and .js is not same.
either include the directory pass in the scrypt path or move the .js file to the same directory

Comment: Did yo omit `<script></script>` from js file?

Comment: Yes, I omitted the `<script></script>` part

Comment: The errors that I'm getting are: `ERROR: 'window' is not defined. [no-undef]` for `window.onscroll = function() {` then `ERROR: 'document' is not defined. [no-undef]` for `var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");` then `ERROR: 'window' is not defined. [no-undef]` for `if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {`

Comment: It seems that I haven't been able to link the main `.html` file to the `.js` files

Comment: Make Sure you add javascript in the footer. <script type="text/javascript" src="themes.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what you said you would like to do.

https://github.com/aaronlilly/examples/tree/master/simpleway

this is the original - https://aaronlilly.github.io/examples/simpleway/simpleorigional.html

and this is with the javascript separated into another file named themes.js
https://aaronlilly.github.io/examples/simpleway/simlesplit.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
</style>
  <script src="themes.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div id="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
  <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```